# What's wrong with my code function to make strcat function in C?

Tags: c, strcat

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char wordsum(char FW[256],char SW[256]){
    int i;
    int j=strlen(FW);
    for (i=0;i<=strlen(SW);i++)
      FW[i+j+1]=SW[i];
    printf("%c",FW);
    return FW;
}

int main()
{
   char F[256];
   char S[256];
   printf("Enter the first word\n");
   gets(F);
   printf("Enter the Second word\n");
   gets(S);
   wordsum(F,S);
   return 0;
}
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code to make `strcat` function. I hope to find the answer.

Comment: Try `FW[i+j]=SW[i]`. (In the current code `SW` is copied right after the terminating `0` of `FW`.)

Comment: ...and write a nul string terminator `'\0'`.

Comment: `printf("%s",FW);`

Comment: `char wordsum(...)` --> `char *wordsum(...)`

Comment: @WeatherVane I guess it is happening already due to `<=`.

Comment: @AlexD mybad well spotted.

Comment: not working
if i have lenght of the first word 4
so the second word will ne in the 5 so i need to add One

Comment: If the first word is length 4 the second word must be written from `FW[4]`. C arrays index from `0`. Two other comments: move printing of result to `main`, and stop using `gets`.

Comment: Lol thanks 
1- char wordsum(.....) to be  char *wordsum(.....). but i dont know why ?
2-printf("%c",FW) to be printf("%s",FW). i know why because its srting not only character
so please tell me why i use * before wordsum ^_^

Comment: Because it returns a pointer: so does the library function `strcat`. Note that an array passed to a function decays to a pointer: `return FW;`

Comment: Note: **never ever** use `gets`! It has been removed from the standard 5 years ago and was deprecated 17 years ago with C99 for good reasons!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the code is written to learn more about the C language. If so, may I present an alternative implementation which does not use strlen(). The intention is to present some of the really nice features in the language. It may be a bit complicated to wrap ones head around the first time, but IIRC the code can be found in K&R's book The C Programming Language.

Here we go:

```
char* mystrcat(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    char *ret = dest;

    while (*dest)
        dest++;

    while ((*dest++ = *src++))
        ;

    return ret;
}
```

The first while-loop finds the end of the destination string. The second while-loop appends the source string to the destination string. Finally, we return a pointer to the original dest buffer.

The function could've been even nicer if it didn't return a pointer.

```
void mystrcat(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    while (*dest)
        dest++;

    while ((*dest++ = *src++))
        ;
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in your function, I've changed and commented them below:

```
char *wordsum(char FW[256],char SW[256]){      // correct function type
   int i;

   int j=strlen(FW); 

   for (i = 0; i <= strlen(SW); i++)
       FW[i+j] = SW[i]; //change 'i + j + 1' to 'i + j'

    printf("%s",FW); //change format specifier as you are printing string not character

    return FW;
}
```

Then dot forget to capture the returned pointer using a `char*` variable in the calling function *(here `main()`)*

```
char *result;
result = wordsum(F,S);
printf("\n%s\n", result);
```

Working example: https://ideone.com/ERlFPE

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in your code. They are:

1) A function can't return an array in C and you don't need to do so. Change the return type from `char` to `void` of `wordsum` and erase the line `return FW;`

2) You want to print a string, right? Format specifier for string is `%s`. So write `printf("%s",FW);` instead of `printf("%c",FW);`.

3) Do this: `FW[i+j]=SW[i];`. Why did you add an extra 1 to `i+j`? Just think logically.

4) Add header file for `strlen()`, it's `<string.h>`.

5) Erase those asterisk marks before and after `FW[i+j]=SW[i];`.